# how to covert coordinates of a selected location to long lat in php?

Tags: php

below given are the coordinates of my selected location

(31.41804293752012, 73.0742385238409),(31.414820024420457, 73.07904504239559),(31.419031763657962, 73.08410905301571),(31.422877099540145, 73.0788304656744)

i want to convert these coordinates to longitude and latitude..kindly help me with this

i have stored each x coordinate into separate array n y coordinates into separate array
below is my code that will inculcate some sense that what am i doing after all...
i just need to know k how to convert these coordinates to lat and long and then those lat to lang to street address.....

```
   function check($point,$x_cordinates,$y_cordinates,$lat,$lon)
{
  $i=$j=$k=0;
   for ($i = 0, $j = $point-1; $i < $point; $j = $i++)
   {
                                                                                       if (($y_cordinates[$i] >  $lat_y != ($y_cordinates[$j] > $lat_y)) &&          ($lon_x < ($x_cordinates[$j] - $x_cordinates[$i]) * ($lat_y - $y_cordinates[$i])  /  ($y_cordinates[$j] - $y_cordinates[$i]) + $x_cordinates[$i]))
                {
             $k = !$k;
                }
   }
   return $k;
}
      $office_id=24;
       $sql="select office_loc from office where office_id='$office_id'LIMIT 1";
       $que=mysql_query($sql);
        if($que)
   {
           $row=mysql_fetch_array($que);
           $loc=$row['office_loc'];
           $loc_wdot_rbrac=explode('(',$loc);
           $loc_wdot_lbrac=str_replace(')', '', $loc_wdot_rbrac);
            $x_cordinates=array();
           $y_cordinates=array();
           foreach ($loc_wdot_lbrac as  $value) 
      {
          # code...
      if (empty($value)) 
       {
           # code...
       contine;
       }
       $loc_wdot_comma=explode(',',$value);
       $x_cordinates[]=$loc_wdot_comma[0];
       $y_cordinates[]=$loc_wdot_comma[1];

       }
        echo '---- Result x ---- <br /><pre>';
       print_r($x_cordinates);
       echo '</pre>';

      echo '---- Result y ---- <br /><pre>';
      print_r($y_cordinates);
      echo '</pre>';
      $lat=31.5546;
      $lon=74.3572;
      $point=count($x_cordinates);
      if(check($point,$x_cordinates,$y_cordinates,$lat,$lon))
         {
            echo"inside";
         }
           else
         {
            echo"out";
         }


          }
            else
         {
                 echo mysql_error(db);
          }
```

and here is the output.....

```
                ---- Result x ---- 
                   Array
             (
               [0] => 
               [1] => 31.41804293752012
               [2] => 31.414820024420457
               [3] => 31.419031763657962
               [4] => 31.422877099540145
              )
               ---- Result y ---- 
               Array
               (
               [0] => 
               [1] =>  73.0742385238409
               [2] =>  73.07904504239559
               [3] =>  73.08410905301571
               [4] =>  73.0788304656744
               )
                      out
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Andreas i have posted the output in the question below the code...the thing is i want to convert these coordinates to either to lon lat or if viable then directly to address

Comment: You can try and use Google APi for the same

Comment: Updated my answer below

Comment: @Andreas Thanks Brother

Comment: Was that what you wanted or did I miss something? Your code was a bit confusing so I just went from input to your expected output

Comment: @Andreas i want to convert these coordinates to street address basically

Comment: In that case you need something more than php, or several hours of typing in adresses and lat/lon. As Apoorv said, you can probably use google maps to do it. Don't know how but I bet it's not that hard.

Comment: @Andreas yea i am trying to work with gmap api thankx for your concern...:)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will do as you will get one extra array with the full match.

```
preg_match_all("/\((\d+\.\d+),\s(\d+\.\d+)\)/", $input, $output);
```

https://3v4l.org/MjUMA

EDIT: To get the x and y arrays as you want in your edit, you can do like this: https://3v4l.org/Llvpg

```
$input = "(31.56215484936523, 74.35487531125546),(31.556669638119804, 74.35487531125546),(31.558351803858574, 74.3627717345953),(31.562886186493845, 74.36109803617)";

preg_match_all("/\((\d+\.\d+),\s(\d+\.\d+)\)/", $input, $output);

$x = $output[1];
$y = $output[2];

Var_dump($x);
var_dump($y);
```